# TypeORM - Auto fill table when running server

Tags: sql, typeorm, user-roles

In TypeORM it is possible to run the migrations when running the server. I have one table called Roles. These are the different roles that a User can have (Admin, User, ...). Is there a way to also auto insert these values into the created Roles table?

I know I can alter the migration file with inserts of each role. But is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [typeorm-seeding](https://github.com/w3tecch/typeorm-seeding) library, it's easy to use, after creating your entities you should create a factory & seeder to run you seeds, a quick example:

```
    Factory
The purpose of a factory is to create new entities with generate data.

Note: Factories can also be used to generate data for testing.

// user.factory.ts
define(User, (faker: typeof Faker) => {
  const gender = faker.datatype.number(1)
  const firstName = faker.name.firstName(gender)
  const lastName = faker.name.lastName(gender)

  const user = new User()
  user.name = `${firstName} ${lastName}`
  user.password = faker.random.word()
  return user
})

// pet.factory.ts
define(Pet, (faker: typeof Faker) => {
  const gender = faker.datatype.number(1)
  const name = faker.name.firstName(gender)

  const pet = new Pet()
  pet.name = name
  pet.age = faker.datatype.number()
  pet.user = factory(User)() as any
  return pet
})
Seeder
And last but not least, create a seeder. The seeder can be called by the configured cli command seed:run. In this case, it generates 10 pets with a owner (User).

Note: seed:run must be configured first. Go to CLI Configuration.

// create-pets.seed.ts
export default class CreatePets implements Seeder {
  public async run(factory: Factory, connection: Connection): Promise<any> {
    await factory(Pet)().createMany(10)
  }
}
```

You can find everything you need in docs